# How do I get rid of these weird folders and files? Preferably without formatting the drive

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, usb, sd-card, far-manager

After copying some files onto both my 16GB Micro SD and my 3.7GB USB drive, come of the folders got corrupted and I can't get rid of them. Windows gives an error, and seems to not be able to do anything about it. I have tried wiping the free space of my USB drive, as it only took a few minutes compared to hours for my Micro SD. I have attached a few screenshots I have.
Note, I copied all of the uncorrupted files with Far Manager.
How do I get rid of these files, preferably without formatting the drives?
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What's on the second screenshot?

Comment: Have you tried `chkdsk`?

Comment: @gronostaj the second screenshot is file manager window with the weird filenames

Comment: @JW0914 yes, and it put the weird files into FOUND.000 with .ck or something and the folders into other files, but left them in correct directories.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to ask about the 3rd screenshot

Comment: @gronostaj it's from TreeSize Free, it shows the size of directories on any drive. I originally used it to find big files on my laptop c drive. also did you mean gornostaj in your name?

Comment: @HighElfWisard No, "gronostaj" is a Polish word for stoat. Did you mean "Wizard" in your name? ;)

Comment: yes and i just noticed. in Russian, gornostaj is a small animal i think a ferret

Answer (score 3):

**Format it.**

- You already have copies of all files that you want to save.
- It's just a few GB of data, so rather quick to copy back.
- Formatting will create a guaranteed good filesystem, whereas cleanup may not.

No reason to not format it at this point. You'll spend more time applying an unreliable solution than going for the obvious, reliable one.

---

Otherwise, the first logical step would be to `chkdsk` the drive. Either use the command line tool or drive's *Properties*, *Tools* tab.

---

This drive may already be nearing the end of its service life. I wouldn't trust any important data to it. Luckily it's just 4 GB, so cheap to replace.

Comment: Sorry, i was writing this in the morning and realized that i moved the files, not copied them... :( theoretically i do have copies on another computer, but a) I do not have access to it's drives. b) even if i did have access, it is ~10 TB and I am not wanting to go through all of that. c) i am not sure if the files are even there.

Comment: @HighElfWisard So just copy your good files from the flash drive/SD card, then format and copy them back? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @HighElfWisard You may want to try [`TestDisk`](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) and/or [`PhotoRec`](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) to try to recover the files then